# NoVNC on iphone/ipad?

Tags: iphone, websocket, vnc-server

I'm trying to connect to a vnc server from iPhone using NoVNC.

I have some issues with "mouse" which behaves very irrationally.

Has anyone experienced the same behaviour ?

(will post code in a few)

Comment: You might want to clarify your question and it's context. Some might downvote it for looking like a discussion about a non-programming topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the noVNC maintainer. Supporting mobile devices with touchscreens has been on my list for a while. I just filed a [issue](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/issues#issue/48) to track this feature.

Supporting [touchscreen interfaces](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/10/touching-and-gesturing-on-the-iphone/) is quite different from normal mouse support. Also, noVNC will probably need to have viewport support for usability and performance reasons on mobile devices.

I do have an iPhone, and I do want to get this functionality working, but I'm not sure when I'll be able to get around to it. Help is always welcome. :-)

Comment: Not sure my skills will help; but will be first to try it out !